# how to encode String into Pattern and retrieve the String

Tags: java

Question closed because I misunderstood the situation. To show my stupidity though, I'll not remove what I wrote.

I'd like to encode a piece of string into Pattern, and get the string back.

I tried:

```
String s = buff.readLine();
Pattern p = new Pattern(s);
```

and use the following to retrieve my string

```
System.out.println(p.toString());
```

But it didn't work, the output is just the "package name@(some random things)... I tried `Pattern p = Pattern.compile (s);` 
but I got an error from the compiler.

Comment: Why do you need to use Pattern?

Comment: @Bo: please add the exact error from toString(), and the compiler error you got for compile(s).  java.util.regex.Pattern has no public constructor, so I can't see how your sample would compile, unless it was some different Pattern class... maybe check your import?

Comment: How about System.out.println(s)? Or are you relying on Pattern to do some validation?

Comment: apologies, it's a bad question.

I just realized that Pattern is a class developed by someone else, not java.util.Regex.Pattern

Comment: you should close the question then

Answer (score 1):

Well I just tried this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Hello");
System.out.println( p.toString() );
```

And it worked, printing out 'Hello'.

Are you importing the java.util.regex.Pattern package?

Answer (score 1):

The javadoc for `Pattern#toString()` seems to indicate that the source of the complete regex is only returned since java 1.5. However, `Pattern#pattern()` does not have a since tag, so it is presumably available since the class was introduced (java 1.4). Try `System.out.println(p.pattern());`

Answer (score 0):

You're using a regex Pattern object to store and retrieve a String.  This makes no sense.  A Pattern is not used for storing Strings.  A Pattern is used for *searching* other strings.  It's a regular expression engine.  Let me give you an example of the use of a Pattern.

We really have 2 objects when using Regular Expressions in Java.  Pattern, and Matcher.

Pattern = A Regular Expression.
Matcher = All of the Matches found when we apply the Pattern to a String.

Let me give you an example of Pattern and Matcher, we'll search for four digits, separated by a colon, like as in time, ie 12:42

```
long timeL;
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*([1234567890]{2}:[1234567890]{2}).*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Match me!  12:42  Match me!");
if (matcher.matches()) {
 String timeStr = matcher.group(1);
 System.out.println("Just the time: "+timeStr);
 System.out.println("The entire String: "+matcher.group(0));
 String[] timeParts = timeStr.split("[:]");
 int hours = Integer.parseInt(timeParts[0]);
 int minutes = Integer.parseInt(timeParts[1]);
 timeL = (hours*60*60*1000) + (minutes*60*1000);
 System.out.println(timeL);
}
```

After we've applied the Pattern to the String, and gotten a Matcher, we ask if the Matcher actually has a Match or not.  You'll notice that we then request group 1, which is the match in the parantheses in: .*([1234567890]{2}:[1234567890]{2}).*
group 0 would be the entire match, and would result in returning the String given.

So, I hope you understand why it's extremely weird to be using a Pattern to store a String.